# Line density with R and spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

I use R and the spatstat package to create a density map of vessels' trajectories using the pixellate function (spatstat). I'm able to create a map and plot the trajectories density.

[image]

Now I would like to improve the design of my map and do something like the maps created by Niels Willems ([Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=kmijvZUAAAAJ&hl=fr)). The image below give an example of what I'm looking to achieve. Do you know what I could do to get this kind of 3D effects ?

[image]

Thanks for your help,

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

If the original trajectories were represented as an object of class `psp` (line segment pattern) then you could have used `spatstat::density.psp` to compute this kind of smoothed image. But if you have already converted them to a pixel image using `pixellate.psp` (with pixel values that tell you how much trajectory length was in each pixel) then you could use `spatstat::blur` to get a smoothed image.